# How to search Single user From LADP:

Tags: findall, adam

I have a method that will search particular User into ADAM.

```
 'set up the LDAP entry object
        objEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & m_strLDAPServer & ":" & m_strLDAPPort & "/" & m_strLDAPEntry)
is the default but it must be set explicitly so that the props array can be passed in
        objSearcher = New DirectorySearcher(objChild, "(objectClass=*)", strProps)
        objSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base

 objSearcher = New DirectorySearcher(objChild, "(objectClass=*)", strProps)
        objSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base
        'carry out the search
        Try
            objResult = objSearcher.FindOne()
        Catch
            objResult = Nothing
        End Try
```

I want to get Results from ADAM 
SQL:  Like **'%strUserName%'**, but  I found only method **FindOne()** that only search the full string "strUserName", but it not performing the SQL Like Operation. 
Any Idea How can I search like SQL LIKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its works fine:

```
eobjEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & m_strLDAPServer & ":" & m_strLDAPPort & "/" & "cn=" & txtUserName & "," & m_strLDAPEntry)
    'set the user name and password, if necessary

    Dim search As New DirectorySearcher()
```

'here search & txtUserName &  works SQL Like Operation 
        objSearcher = New DirectorySearcher(objEntry, "(cn=" & txtUserName & ")")
        objSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base And SearchScope.OneLevel
        Dim result As SearchResult = search.FindOne()